# How do Bombers work in BF4

Tags: battlefield-4

I get a notice that a friendly/enemy bomber has been deployed.  How do I get into it, and what level of controllability is there?

Comment: Basically you have to sit around a trailer and fight off the other people in line.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The China Rising Bomber is deployed from one of the control points that is held by your team on Conquest mode. The trailer you need to enter is a yellow "portable" box with a radar disk on the side. Once you enter it, the system connects you to an inbound bomber which flys fairly quickly across the map. The bomber can drop 4 JDAM bombs and a cruise missile during each "load" and if you're quick you can get two loads per run.

You can click on the ground where the bombs are to be deployed to, however with a 5-6 second flight time they are not suited to moving targets, more likely meant for stationary infantry and vehicles. You cannot control the speed or direction of the plane, but you can deploy a bank of 30 flares to avoid any missiles fired at it.

Once you get a kill you unlock the SUAV for the recon kit, a small, battery powered, remote-controllable plane that can spot enemies, lase targets, and (currently) roadkill as many people as you can hit before the battery runs out.

Once the plane has finished it's run and you exit the command unit, there is a cooldown timer before it can be used again.

Comment: Can't wait to play around with this! +1

Comment: As for actually how you switch between JDAM and cruise missile munitions...I haven't worked that out yet.

Comment: One thing to mention is that when the bomber is available, you will see a grey bomber icon overlaid on top of the bomber command box (trailer with the dish).  At that point, you can go up to the door and press E to communicate with it and drop ordinance.

Comment: @tombull89: I'd imagine that first you'd have to unlock cruise missile through the "Mother of All Bombs" assignment (15 bomber kills + destroy enemy bomber).